# break multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to break down an multidimensional array into further single arrays.
Here is my array display..

```
Array
(
    [family] => opensans
    [variants] => Array
        (
            [0] => 300
            [1] => 300italic
            [2] => regular
            [3] => italic
            [4] => 600
            [5] => 600italic
        )

    [subsets] => Array
        (
            [0] => cyrillic-ext
            [1] => vietnamese
            [2] => greek-ext
            [3] => greek
            [4] => cyrillic
            [5] => latin-ext
            [6] => latin
        )

)
```

I want family/variants/subsets in different arrays so please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: @Rizier123, yes i tried but did not work.
foreach($values as $v){
     print_r($v);
    }

Comment: I wont be very difficult if you would have tried!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Vipin That's already a good start. Now you only need to use they key as variable (Change your foreach head) and assign the array to it.

Comment: @Rizier123, forgive me for my misunderstanding but i did not get your words.

Comment: @Vipin No problem. Give it at most 10 minutes: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php And learn about the two different syntaxes + http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds to simple but if that is your complete array all you need to do is

Assuming your big array is called `$bigArray`

```
$family   = $bigArray['family'];
$variants = $bigArray['variants'];
$subsets  = $bigArray['subsets'];

echo $family;
print_r($variants);
print_r($subsets);
```

`$family` of course will not be an array as `$bigArray['family']` is not an array so `$family` will just be a string.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use dynamic variables([php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)):

```
foreach ($array as $newVar => $newData) {
  $$newVar = $newData;
 }
 var_dump($family);
 var_dump($variants);
 var_dump($subsets);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let say that your array of

```
Array
(
    [family] => opensans
    [variants] => Array
        (
            [0] => 300
            [1] => 300italic
            [2] => regular
            [3] => italic
            [4] => 600
            [5] => 600italic
        )

    [subsets] => Array
        (
            [0] => cyrillic-ext
            [1] => vietnamese
            [2] => greek-ext
            [3] => greek
            [4] => cyrillic
            [5] => latin-ext
            [6] => latin
        )

)
```

is stored in a variable `$myArr`

You then need to do this.

```
foreach($myArr as $key => $value):    
    ${key} = $value;
endforeach;
```

Should give you 3 arrays stored as `$family`, `variants` & `subsets`. Not sure about family, is that a string? in which case it will be string again unless you force it as a array.